# How to autostart `xautolock` in Lubuntu?

Tags: lock-screen, autostart

I put the command in:

```
.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

but it doesn't seem to be executed.  I found a strange workaround (see below).

Answer (score 0):

I put the command in:

```
.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
```

but I found that it fails to invoke the command `xautolock`,  unless I put a script file inside the `autostart` file and then invoke `xautolock` from that script.

Don't know why but it works.